# pass data from VC1 to VC4

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uinavigationcontroller

I have a basic question about data management. If I want to use data from `VC1` in `VC4`, do I need to pass them through `VC2` and `VC3` even if they are not using the data?

I'm using `navigationController`and right now I have the following scenario: In `VC4`, I'll make a connection to `webserver` to retrieve some data according to what user selected in `VC1`.

I declare `properties` on `header`files of `VC2`, `VC3` and `VC4`.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString`.

Now, I pass this `@property`using `prepareForSegue`method, since I'm using `storyboards`. So basically, they look like this on `VC1`, `VC2`and `VC3`:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
        NextVC *next = (NextVC*)segue.destinationViewController;
        next.myString = self.myString;
    }
}
```

Now, this works fine for me, I just want to make sure this is good programming practice and if there isn't a better way to do this. Especially when we have a lot of data, since not always we are passing only simple `NSStrings`. I'm just concerned about allocating `memory`to objects I'm not using, no matter the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

Alternatively, you can always use the **`viewControllers`** property of your **`UINavigationController`**.

You can access the `VC1` from `VC4` by calling:

```
UIViewController *vc1 = self.navigationController.viewControllers[0];
```

And then access the data of the `VC1` that you need.